# Printing whole numbers with {#} in C#?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I haven't found anything relevant to it.

So, how can I print `0` for the numbers having a **whole square root** with the following code?

```
for (n = 1.0; n <= 10; n++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Fractional Part : {0 :#.####}", (Math.Sqrt(n) - (int) Math.Sqrt(n)));
}
```

**Current O/P:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a leading zero on the other fractional results is acceptable, and since your result is always in the range of `[0,1)`, you could just change `#.####` to `0.####`.

```
for (var n = 1.0; n <= 10; n++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fractional Part : {0:0.####}", (Math.Sqrt(n) - (int) Math.Sqrt(n)));
}
```

Results:

```
Fractional Part : 0
Fractional Part : 0.4142
Fractional Part : 0.7321
Fractional Part : 0
Fractional Part : 0.2361
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using [The numeric `"N"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with `4` precision?

```
for (var n = 1.0; n <= 10; n++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fractional Part : {0}", 
                      (Math.Sqrt(n) - (int)Math.Sqrt(n)).ToString("N4"));
}
```

Result is:

```
Fractional Part : 0.0000
Fractional Part : 0.4142
Fractional Part : 0.7321
Fractional Part : 0.0000
Fractional Part : 0.2361
Fractional Part : 0.4495
Fractional Part : 0.6458
Fractional Part : 0.8284
Fractional Part : 0.0000
Fractional Part : 0.1623
```